# Sound and sound applet disappeared and won't come back

Tags: 10.04, sound, indicator, troubleshooting

Recently (I don't don't know when, might have been after an update) the sound indicator  disappeared from my panel, and I haven't been getting any sound either. I tried installing the `indicator-sound` package, but all I got was this error message:

```
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  indicator-sound: Depends: libido-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
  E: Broken packages
```

Seems to be a bug, but how do I get around it? Could I install an older version of libido? If so, how do I do that?

Everything had worked fine until a couple days ago, so I'm sure that the package is the problem.

EDIT:The command `$ dpkg --get-selections | grep libido` returns the following output:

```
libido-0.1-0                    deinstall
```

---

Ok, that's embarassing. Yesterday I uninstalled and reinstalled the libido package half a dozen times, and the indicator-sound package kept reporting the same error. Today, however, I just installed the libido package and now the indicator-sound package installed with no errors. Maybe the system needed a reboot or something.

(Should I answer my own question or just wait for a moderator to close it?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I manage to solve it. I just installed the libido package and now the indicator-sound package installed with no errors. Maybe the system needed a reboot with the package uninstalled or something. If someone's having this problem, you can try:

```
sudo apt-get remove libido-0.1-0 
sudo apt-get remove indicator-sound
```

Restart your computer (this is the part that seems to have solved it). And then reinstall both packages.

```
sudo apt-get install libido-0.1-0 
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
```

It's worth mentioning that, even after the reboot, the terminal kept reporting error messages when I tried to install  indicator-sound. But after I reinstalled libido manually, the indicator-sound installed without issues.